# Avoid creating a new NuGet package just to test code when the package is consumed by a Net6 application

Tags: c#, nuget, .net-6.0, nuget-package

I have an application that consumes some libraries, developed by me, via NuGet packages. Before migrating to Net6 from .Net framework, I used to test the code changes of my libraries by simply replacing the dlls in the NuGet folder contained in the "packages" folder of the application. The dll are actually 2: one native c++ code dll and a C++/CLI managed dll that wraps it. After compiling, the modified dlls were copied to the bin folder and could be run. I liked this workflow as I could test the changes in my library code without creating a new NuGet package with a new version number each time (and without updating the application to a new package). After migrating to Net6 this has become impossible as there is no more a "packages" folder.
Thank you very much,
CR

I tried to replace the dlls in the .npkg file (editing it as a .zip) but the new code doesn't run. I think that the NuGet package is cached somewhere on my machine and a new package with a new version needs to be created in order to get the new code executed. Is there a way to avoid it?

Comment: Why not publish a beta version and then replace the libraries in the cached location for each change?

Comment: Do you have a project or Organisation feed for your own nugets? If so, you can publish preview / beta / rc "releases" and test against those.

Comment: @marsze You made me realize that I can use the beta, alpha etc. naming in my version as: 1.0.1-beta.12, 1.0.1-beta.5, 1.0.1-beta, 1.0.1-alpha.2, 1.0.1-alpha etc. still I need to create a new NuGet package, however is ok

Comment: #Fildor yes we have a NuGet server in the organization, I think it's ok to publish beta and alpha version there. I just hoped it could be possible to simply replace the dll instead of publishing a new package each time I need to test a change as I did before.

Comment: Whatever you're using to test it should be part of the solution so you can make a project reference to it. You're testing the functionality, not the packaging, so that difference is unimportant.

Comment: @madreflection actually I have a smaller test application that references the library project without the NuGet. However I cannot test the full functionality of the larger application with this smaller application as it would require a lot of work.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using the new SDK-style project? If so try updating the .csproj file to use a `Reference` item instead of `PackageReference`, i.e.

```
<ItemGroup>
<Reference Include="MyCppCli.dll" > <HintPath>C:/path/to/MyCppCli.dll</HintPath></Reference>
</ItemGroup>
```